# Rails feed from multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771548/rails-creating-an-all-activity-feed-from-multiple-models) question, I have created a controller:

```
@activities = (@plays + @wants).sort_by {|a| a.created_at}.reverse
```

and a view:

```
- @plays.each do |play|
  You played #{play.game.name}
```

However it can not be displayed: `undefined method 'play' for #Want:0x007f39ab8e99e0`

How can I access different fields of each dependent model, and their names?
Like:

```
- @activities.each do |activity|
  - if activity.model_name = Play
   You played #{activity.model.name}
  - else      
   You want #{play.want.name}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing with `if activity.model_name = Play` is an assignation, you can do the same using `==` to compare the class from such object and to select the attribute corresponding to the object from that specific class.

You're using the variable `activity` to refer the objects inside `@activities`, so, `play` doesn't exist within the `each` block.

You could try with:

```
- @activities.each do |activity|
  - if activity.class == Play
    You played #{activity.attribute_for_a_play_object}
  - else      
    You want #{activity.attribute_for_a_non_play_object}
```